# How to pass structures into CUDA device?

Tags: cuda, structure

I've been stuck on this for a while. When I pass my structures into CUDA via kernel parameters, they contain no data and everything is undefined inside of them.

Out in host global space

```
struct matl1
{
    static const double cond;
};

const double matl1::cond = 420.5;
```

Then inside of main()

```
matl1 * h_matl1 = (matl1*)malloc(sizeof(matl1));
matl1 * d_matl1;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_matl1, sizeof(matl1));
cudaMemcpy(d_matl1, h_matl1, sizeof(matl1), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
kernel<<<1,1>>>(d_matl1,...);
```

Then inside of kernel()

```
__global__ void kernel(matl1* d_matl1,...)
{
double cond = d_matl1->cond;
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
error : identifier "matl1::cond" is undefined in device code
```

As a quick test, if I do the following on the host in main()

```
cout << h_matl1->cond << endl;
```

It shows me the correct output of 420.5. I am not sure why this isn't making it into the device.

Here's the rest of my output

uild started: Project: test_struct, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------

Compiling CUDA source file kernel.cu...

C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test_struct\test_struct>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o Debug\kernel.cu.obj "C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test_struct\test_struct\kernel.cu" 
1>C:/Users/User/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/test_struct/test_struct/kernel.cu(15): error : identifier "matl1::cond" is undefined in device code

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 5.5.targets(592,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o Debug\kernel.cu.obj "C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test_struct\test_struct\kernel.cu"" exited with code 2.

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: It seens to work for me.  See [here](http://pastebin.com/2NLxa5Sc)  I'm doing this on linux with CUDA 5.5.  You'll need to provide more specifics and an actual complete example, just as I have, so we can see all the code and output of the compiler.  Identify the platform (linux, windows, etc.), which version of CUDA, and provide the complete code, and the complete output from the compile command, as well as the complete compile command.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your error if I do this:

```
struct matl1
{
    static const double cond;
};



__global__ void kernel(matl1* d_matl1)
{
double cond = d_matl1->cond;
printf("cond = %lf\n", cond);
}

const double matl1::cond = 420.5;
```

But not if I do this:

```
struct matl1
{
    static const double cond;
};

const double matl1::cond = 420.5;

__global__ void kernel(matl1* d_matl1)
{
double cond = d_matl1->cond;
printf("cond = %lf\n", cond);
}
```

You need to define the constant initializer before the kernel definition.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/2NLxa5Sc) is a complete example that works for me.

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong on my end then. Even with your code, (nearly identical to my original), I am getting the same error:

    'error : identifier "matl1::cond" is undefined in device code'.

I am using the following

OS : Windows 7 Pro x64, 

GPU : GTX Titan, with latest 331 drivers, 

Compiler : Visual Studio Pro 2012 with Nvidia NSight, 

CUDA Version : 5.5, 

Compute/SM arch : Both set to 3.5. Could it be my compiler?

Comment: I will also post the rest of the compiler output tomorrow morning. I cannot post another 8 hours, and the output it too long to fit or even break up into sections for the comments here.

Comment: This is a peculiarity of the Windows toolchain. Undecorated constants get compiled into both host and device code with gcc based toolchains, but not with the Microsoft compiler. I have had similar questions here before where what works on Linux and OS X fails on a Win 32 system.

Comment: and in this case I think the fact it works in gcc is an accident. my interpretation of the data model.would be that any structure or class data member is defined only in the memory space the host structure in defined in. in this case that should only be the host memory space.

Comment: @talonmies why don't you provide an answer and I'll delete mine.